# Conflict (line break)

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm using the flexbox classes inside a column ( d-flex align-items-center justify-content-left ) to control the placement of the texts ( h1 and p ), but using flexbox to conflict with the content line break. paragraph tag. How do I get the content of the paragraph below the content of the h1 tag? Below is the code:

```
<div class="col d-flex align-items-center justify-content-left">
 <h1>App Name</h1>
 <p>Content em desenvolvimento</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align items, one per row, change `h1` and `p` display property to block so it gets rendered in one line, do it by adding `d-block` class to each element:

```
<div class="col d-flex align-items-center justify-content-left">
 <h1 class="d-block">App Name</h1>
 <p class="d-block">Content em desenvolvimento</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.flex-wrap` then add `.w-100` to elements that should take the whole width.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col d-flex flex-wrap">
      <h1 class="w-100 text-center">App Name</h1>
      <p class="w-100">Content em desenvolvimento</p>
      <p class="p-1">flex<br>paragraph</p>
      <p class="p-1">flex<br>paragraph</p>
      <p class="p-1">flex<br>paragraph</p>
      <p class="p-1">flex<br>paragraph</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```